# Script to block popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, adblock

AdBlock sometimes fails to block popups, so using Greasemonkey I want to write my own popup blocker using jQuery.

Is there a way I can intercept the clicks and detect if it's going to open a popup?

```
$('.popupLauncher').each(function(){
    if( /* $(this) will open a popup */ ){
        return false;
    }
});
```

With what can I replace `/* $(this) will open a popup */` ?

Comment: Not reliably. `if ($(this.).attr("onclick").indexOf('open') !=-1)` might work in some cases. It will take you less time to add the regexp to adblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you open a popup using javascript ?

```
window.open(url, etc, etc, etc);
```

So in theory you can re-write the `window.open` function to do something else rather than opening a popup.

```
window.open = null;
```

However it might break the page scripts if `window.open` is `undefined` when being called.
Therefore I think the best approach would be:

```
window.open = function(){
   return;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but as i said, in theory it should work.

Comment: A popup can be open with `<a href="..." target="_window">` or something similar, too, can't it?

Comment: That is the case when you click on an AD. But if you click on a normal link that points to a video for instance, the only way to open a popup beside playing the video will be using window.open

Comment: Technically. `return;` can be omitted to make it shorter (effect is the same).